# How to see what the orientation is for an image selected from image gallery

Tags: android, image

For  my app, I need to be able to find the orientation for an image that a user selects from the photo gallery. This stems from the fact that some devices(such as Samsung phones) save images as landscape; Nexus devices, on the other hand, save as portrait. Currently, in my app, if a user selects an image from gallery on a Samsung phone, the image is being loaded in landscape; obviously, I need to rotate the image. The problem is that when I try to get the orientation of an image, zero is returned for the rotation value(both for landscape and portrait images). I currently have no way to to figure out whether I need to rotate these images. Thanks!

edit: Here is some of the code I'm using to get the orientation which isn't working. I'm first allowing the user to pick the image from gallery

```
           Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
           pickIntent.setType("image/*");
           pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

           Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
           File photoFile = null;
           try {
               photoFile = createImageFile();
           } catch (IOException ex) {
           }
           // Continue only if the File was successfully created

           takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, savedUri);

           String pickTitle = "Select or take a new Picture"; // Or get from strings.xml
           Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle);
           chooserIntent.putExtra
                   (
                           Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                           new Intent[] { takePhotoIntent }
                   );

           startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
```

Then, in the onActivityResult, we're setting the Uri. Afterwards, I attempt to get the orientation using this code:

```
       ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(picUri.getPath());

       String orientString = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
       int orientation = orientString != null ? Integer.parseInt(orientString) : ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
       if(orientation == 0){
           orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
       }
       if(orientation == 0) {
           String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
           Cursor cur = managedQuery(picUri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
           if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
               orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
           }
       }
```

Comment: For JPEGs, examine the EXIF `Orientation` header.

Comment: Yep. This is what I'm currently doing.

Comment: This isn't the same as "Camera picture Uri null path". This is a different problem. He's getting a NPE; I'm getting a zero returned for the orientation.

Comment: However, it is the same underlying problem: you think that `picUri.getPath()` is useful. It is not. Quoting myself from that answer: "[A `Uri` is not a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html)... You need to switch to EXIF logic that can handle an InputStream, such as [this code culled from the AOSP Mms app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/tree/master/camera/src/com/android/mms/exif).". There are other stream-friendly EXIF parsing bits of code around; this happens to be the one I have a link to handy.